# Replacing a non-basepoint free line bundle by a basepoint free one

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, brill-noether

In his paper “Brill-noether-petri without degenerations”, Lazarsfeld says the following in in Corollary 1.4.

Statement - Assume that every member of the linear series $|C_0|$ in a K3 surface is reduced and irreducible. Then for every smooth curve $C$ in the linear system and every line bundle $A$ on $C $, one has $\rho(A)\geq 0$ where $\rho(A)=g(C)-h^0(A)h^1(A)$.

Proof: 
Let $B$ be a special globally general  line bundle on a smooth curve $C$. If $B^*\otimes\omega_C$ has base divisor $\Delta$, then $B(\Delta)$ is again basepoint free. Thus we can assume in the statement that both $A$ and $A^*\otimes \omega_C$ are globally generated.

I don’t understand the above.

1) First of all, how to prove that $B(\Delta)$ is basepoint free?

2) Now $B(\Delta)$ and $\omega_C\otimes B^*(-\Delta)$ are globally generated. But how does that imply the statement for $B$? In other words why is it enough to check for line bundles of the form $B(\Delta)$?

3) In the proof of the main theorem, it says (from the above remark) if $D$ is any effective divisor on $C$ and $\Delta$ is the divisor of basepoints of $|D|$, then the injectivity of the Petri map $\mu_0$  for $O_C(D-\Delta)$ implies the injectivity of $\mu_0$ for $O_C(D)$? Why is this?

Grateful for any help!

Comment: Use Riemann-Roch to note that $B(p)$ has an extra section as compared with $B$ if and only if $p$ is a base-point for $B^{*}\otimes\omega_C$. Secondly, note that in this situation $h^{0}(B(p))$ has increased while $h^{1}(B(p))$ has stayed the same.

Comment: @Kapil, thanks. I checked this based on your hint. It solves part (1) of my doubt. Any leads on part 2 and 3? Why is enough to consider line bundles of this kind?

Comment: About (2). That was hinted at in my second sentence: $h^{0}(B(\Delta))\geq h^{0}(B)$ and $h^{1}(B(\Delta))=h^{1}(B)$. So, if $g(C)$ is greater than this product then it is greater than the smaller product. No input for (3) at the moment. One probably needs to write the appropriate long exact sequence.